# Error in normalize path R shiny

Tags: path, shiny, rstudio, normalize, shinydashboard

This is my first question on stack overflow so I apologize in advance in case I ask a rather vague or difficult question.

I have been working on developing a small web app that extracts granular data from facebook pages using the Rfacebook package. I have completed the data extraction function for this web app and have now moved to developing the shiny UI and server functions using shinydashboard.

I have completed one phase of the dashboard development, and I had tested it multiple times successfully, however once I closed and saved RStudio and then relaunched it, I kept getting this error whenever I try runApp.

> Warning: Error in normalizePath: path[1]="C:\Users\Adel\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIr7Hkl\widgetbinding16a456f01dfa": The system cannot find the file specified
>   Stack trace (innermost first):
>       1: shiny::runApp
>   Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
>     path[1]="C:\Users\Adel\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIr7Hkl\widgetbinding16a456f01dfa": The system cannot find the file specified

I tried removing and reinstalling all relevant packages, however it was a failure. 
I have also tried to create a file "widgetbinding16a456f01dfa" in the specified path, it resulted in rendering the shinydashboard, but it was non-functional dashboard. 
Furthermore, I tried changing projects on RStudio, the shinydashboard worked, however whenever I close and relaunch RStudio I receive the same error but vaguely different filenames (i.e widgetbinding[..different numbers])

There has been limited information about this bug online, I have a hunch it's an RStudio error and not a shiny one.

Below is the code I used for the ui.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(Rfacebook)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(

    textInput("f_id", "Enter Facebook Page ID", value = "Enter ID ..."),
    dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                   label = 'Input Date',
                   start = Sys.Date() - 2, end = Sys.Date() + 2),
    actionButton("go", "Go")
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    dashboardBody(
      dataTableOutput("table1",height = 5, width = "20") 
    )  
)     )

shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(header,sidebar,body))
```

Below is the code I wrote for the server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

  table <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    facebook_analyzer(input$f_id, since = format(input$dateRange[1])
                      , until = format(input$dateRange[2]))
})  

  output$table1 <-  renderDataTable(
     datatable((table()[,c("poster_name","poster_id","post_content","date_of_post")]), 
               options = list(pageLength = 5, deferRender = TRUE )))
  })
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated, I have been trying to debug this error for two days. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that this is related to the `htmlwidgets` package (see https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/master/R/utils.R line 55), or a package that uses it (for example `DT`). Can you post the package versions you used? (use `sessionInfo()`). Also try to install the github version of `DT` see if it helps.

Comment: similar error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591969/r-cannot-normalize-path-or-add . Did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error. I created a folder `app` and copied the two files into it; and it all runs fine. So, a *later version* of the packages might address this issue (more than four years have passed since this questions was asked). Furthermore, I'd ensure the files `server.R` and `ui.R` are in the same folder, and the working directory is set to the app folder (also this shouldn't be necessary).

The following might not apply to the stated problem directly, since it occurred in the context of `library(gfonts)` and `setup_font(id = "roboto",output_dir = "www",variants = "regular")`, but the error message is similar:

> Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
> path[1]="www": The system cannot find the file specified

In my case, I created the folder (`www`) and this resolved the issue.

Generally, the command `normalizePath('myFolder')` returns the above messages if the directory does not exist.

Since, the original question contained a path. One needs to check if the path (and file) exists. If it exists the access rights have to be checked. If it does not exist the library creating it needs to be identified (`...widgetbinding...` >> `htmlwidgets`), and checked whether a newer release addresses the issue, or some other work-around (e.g. shorter paths, different folder,...).