# R: warning/error when calling normalizePath(...) or adding to .libPath(...)

Tags: r, path, cran, lib

I have a shared computer. If I login with windows userA, I can run the following:

```
normalizePath("//mydrive/my/path", "/")
```

and it returns:

```
"\\\\mydrive/my/path"
```

However if login to windows under userB, I get this message:

> Warning message: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash,
>   mustWork) :   path[1]="//mydrive/my/path": An unexpected network
>   error occurred

What does it mean? This has important consequences, as it prevents to add `"//mydrive/my/path"` to the `.libPaths()` when running under userB, e.g `.libPaths(new="//mydrive/my/path")`, it prints the same warning, then as soon as I try to use a package that is in this lib location, it show the **ERROR**:

> Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
>   path[1]="//mydrive/my/path": An unexpected network error occurred

---

Here are the details of my session under userA:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

Here are the details of my session under userB:

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

Finally, I also noticed the following warning on userB, which could be linked to the same issue:

> WARNING: You are configured to use the CRAN mirror at
>   https://cran.rstudio.com/. This mirror supports secure (HTTPS)
>   downloads however your system is unable to communicate securely with
>   the server (possibly due to out of date certificate files on your
>   system). Falling back to using insecure URL for this mirror.

Comment: sorry, why the downvote?

Comment: Does the path you're giving it actually exist for both users? The warning would suggest it does not.

Comment: @thomas yes the path does exist for both users! dir.exists returns TRUE under both login....

Comment: Weird. Sorry I don't have any idea what could cause this then.